# How can nodes in a material tree be hidden based on a condition?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the problem that I'd like the `data.source` of my material tree to *include more nodes* than the actual displayed tree. The reason for this is because I'd like to use the `getDescendants` method of the tree control, so I need those nodes to be present on the dataSource, just not displayed in the DOM to the user. How can this be achieved? I am using FlatTree.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to introduce a new `mat-tree-node` element:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
          [treeControl]="treeControl">
  
  <mat-tree-node style="display: hidden;"
                 *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: isHidden">
    <!-- Hidden node. -->
  </mat-tree-node>

  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: displayExpandable"
                 matTreeNodePadding>
  <!-- rest of your code -->

</mat-tree>
```

However, take care with the "expandable" property on the FlatTreeNodes. This property is apparently used by the `getDescendants` method. So in order for everything to work properly, your code will look something like this in the ts file:

```
  displayExpandable = (_: number, node: MyFlatTreeNode) => node.children?.some(child => !this.isHidden(_, child));

  isHidden = (_: number, node: MyFlatTreeNode) => your condition goes here;


  private _transformer = (node: MyFlatTreeNode, level: number): MyFlatTreeNode => {
    return {
      ...node,
      
      // ATTENTION: This property seems to be used by getDescendants method, so don't exclude hidden children here!
      expandable: node.children != null && node.children.length > 0,

      level: level
    };
  };
```